# Problem with visual force tab click the entire page is Postback

Tags: visualforce

I have an Visual Force tab when I click the tab the entire page is Postedback instead I want  only the iframe to refresh
and also I need Ajax loading image when I click the tab and iframe is refreshing..
here is the code snipet which I used

```
<apex:page sidebar="true">
   <apex:iframe src="https://MyCustomURL" scrolling="true"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Have you tried with canvas ?It does exactly what you want

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible. The visualforce tab and the link to it are hard connected in Salesforce. So if you click on the tab link the visualforce page is called and there is no possibility (standard) to customize this link. You can try to create a Javascript click listener for the tab link on your visualforce page and then prevent the page reload and just reload the iframe, but this will be like some kind of hack soluition.